# Макрос в Excel таблице

Tags: excel

Народ всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, как наладить работу макроса в Excel таблице. В чем суть:

Есть 2 листа, в 1 есть некий диапазон при вводе данных, в который эти данные должны добавляться в лист 2. Использую макрос:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D500,F6:F500,H6:H500,J6:J500,L6:L500")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
           Application.EnableEvents = False
        newVal = Target
        Application.Undo
        oldval = Target
        If Len(oldval) <> 0 And oldval <> newVal Then
            Target = Target & "-" & newVal
        Else
            Target = newVal
        End If
        If Len(newVal) = 0 Then Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
    
    Dim lReply As Long
 
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6:E500,G6:G500,I6:I500,K6:K500,M6:M500")) Is Nothing Then
     If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
       If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Client"), Target) = 0 Then
          lReply = MsgBox("???????? ????????? ??? " & _
                         Target & " ? ?????????? ???????", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
          If lReply = vbYes Then
              Range("Client").Cells(Range("Client").Rows.Count + 1, 1) = Target
          End If
       End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Но суть в том, что скрипт вроде, как и работает, но на лист 2 данные не добавляются. Подскажите знатоки что делать, пожалуйста, или где ошибка.

Пример файла: https://yadi.sk/d/1puqVuWDDthrXw

Comment: Заголовок - прям в точку! Сразу задача понятна, ведь макрос в Excel один-единственный существует :) Код в сообщение нужно копировать не в английской раскладке, тогда кириллица на месте останется. ===  *но на лист 2 данные не добавляются* - естественно, таблица в примере пустая. Зачем для примера 500 ПУСТЫХ строк?! Над было и листы поудалять... Как помогать, если Вы так безалаберно относитесь к созданию вопроса и примеру?

Comment: @vikttur Я предполагал что человек скачает таблицу откроет ее и поймет в чем причина нажав альт f11 поймет что не так. Возможно я смогу создать документ отвечающий вашим параметрам и вы мне поможете?

Comment: Человек скачал, открыл... и закрыл. Пример - простая демонстрация. Зачем 500 строк, да еще пустых? Зачем в таком случае вообще пример? Можно же было заполнить 2-3 для примера, остальное удалить? По вопросу - закомментируйте строку `On Error Resume Next` и сами увидите проблему

Comment: И перестаньте уже брать объект `Range` из пустоты! Это один частых источников ошибок. Определяйте его от книги / листа. Например так: `Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")` ну или определяйте рабочий лист явно в виде переменной. По коду не понятно, находятся ли `Target` и `Range("A1")` на одном листе, или на разных. Проверьте, какие диапазоны задействованы при работе

Comment: Проверьте последовательность выполнения расчета условных выражений. А еще лучше - расставьет скобки таким образом, что бы они явно читались без справочника приоритетов логических операторов. Например вот это условие: `Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D500,F6:F500,H6:H500,J6:J500,L6:L500")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1` совершенно не понятно, какой результат вернет.